# How do I get the time that socket-io disconnect & the current time that close app in background?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, socket.io

I want to know these time to get offline message,but I don't know how to get these time.

I use this function to detect app closed,but the print doesn't show up.

what's wrong about this .

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

print("********exit")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How you are testing? applicationWillTerminate will be called when app terminated menas killed by user or system so you can not see print in terminal. One thing you can do is just store time in User Default, so when next time you open app you can check last time app terminated.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let now = Date()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(now, forKey: "exitTime")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "exitTime") ?? "exit time nil")
    return true
}
```

Other option, You have to enable "Application supports iTunes file sharing" (UIFileSharingEnabled) in Info.plist file. then you can dump all print message in log file. then you can check all log mesaage.